# windows 7 certificate store - certificate disapear/get lost

Tags: windows, certificate

We are running Windows 7 pro 64bit and using certificates for authentication. The certifactes are stored in the "*My*" certification store.

The problem is that about 5% if our user base lose their certificate from one day to another. The windows event log dont provide us enough info so that we could even start digging into the problem. We also can not reproduce the issue right now, it happens approximately  1 - 2 times per month for any of this 5% of our user base - the other 95% never had that problem.

Is there a way to log which program access the certification store and what it modifies there? I tried it with *CAPI2* log enabled but it doenst write a log entry when a certificate gets deleted/disapears, it just logs when a new one is inserted.

First step for me would be to reproduce the problem and then try to solve it. At the moment im a little bit lost because i dont know where to start. There is no correlation between the users as far as i can tell right now.

any help or tips is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Starting in Windows 8 / Server 2012 there are new Event logs to track changes to the certificate stores:

```
Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-User/Operational
Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle-System/Operational
```

More info on [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14250.certificate-services-lifecycle-notifications.aspx)

Unfortunately, these are not available in Windows 7.

What you can try is monitoring access to the private key files, they are located in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\[UserA’s SID]\
```

You could enable auditing on that directory, I haven't done that in a long time, but it may provide you with some hints on what is happening.